# Combining data frames with missing data frames with rbind

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I am using the following command for combining data from different dataframes.Some of the data frames are missing like data 4 etc.,

```
filings<- rbind.pages(list(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5))
Error in stopifnot(is.list(pages)) : object 'data4' not found
```

I am getting the above error. I have about 1000 data frames and there are some missing dataframes which are not known. Is there way I can tackle this issue to skip missing data frames?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
possibleDfs <- paste0('data', 1:1000)
existingDfIndices <- sapply(possibleDfs, exists)
existingDfs <- mget(possibleDfs[existingDfIndices])

do.call(rbind, existingDfs)
```

First, we created a vector of the names of the data.frames:

```
head(possibleDfs)
[1] "data1" "data2" "data3" "data4" "data5" "data6"
```

Then, we used `sapply(possibleDfs, exists)` to get a logical vector indicating which data.frames exist.

We then subseted `possibleDfs` with `existingDfIndices` to get the names of the data.frames that exist, to which we apply `mget` to obtain a list of those data.frames.

Lastly, we use `do.call` and `rbind` to bind all of the data.frames.

Comment: I downloaded data from scraping creating data1<- fromJSON(url, flatten=TRUE) till data 1000. The problem i am facing now is it is reporting data 1.2, 1.3 which are basically the columns when i run the sapply. But i want to combine them as a data frame like binding pages.

Comment: Is there a way i can restrict to get only the data frames with integer values?

Comment: What library are you using for fromJSON?

Comment: Yes I used fromJSON and this code worked after i assigned it to a vector  testdata<- do.call(rbind, existingDfs)